# Add in Remote event receiver for sharepoint permission issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, event-receivers

I have trying to debug a remote event receiver , I have already published to azure.Now when i launch the app in debug mode even after logging in one more window pops up eventhough i have given sufficient permission in appmanifest file. Even if i try to add app manually it gives this error :Your tenant administrator has to approve this app

[image]